# unable to post video file with angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am getting `success = true` but my file path is wrong. I am capturing video and then handing over the location path of that video to my post call to upload the video on server. In `POSTMAN` request it is submitting the video and giving response `success = true` with `path: app/uploads/jobs/12_524.mp4` however **in the app I just get the path without extension of .mp4**

here is the call

```
$rootScope.uploadQuestion = function (file) {
           //file is complete path of file in device  = localURL: "cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/20170801_142942.mp4"
            var form = new FormData();
            form.append("job_id", "4124");
            form.append("question_id", "11");
            form.append("user_id", "159931");
            form.append("file", file);
            console.log('File: ' + file);
// prints this: File: cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/20170801_142942.mp4
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
                url: 'http://services.someservice.com/upload.php',
                //transformRequest: angular.identity,
                cache: false,
                timeout: 300000
            }).then(function (response) {
                var data = response.data;
                var status = response.status;
                if (status == '200') {
                    if (data.success == "true") {
                        alert('uploading...');
                    }
                }
            }).catch(function (response) {

                throw response;
            });

        }
```